# getting images from list

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, attachments

I can data from all columns but cannot get attachment. how do i get attachment and load it to image tag. Here is code i have so far to get data from list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
debugger;
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Mylist");


var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); //The Query object. This is used to query for data in the List

query.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit></RowLimit>3</View>');

var items = list.getItems(query);

context.load(list); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.
context.load(items);

var table = $("#tblcategories");
var innerHtml = "<tr><td>ID</td><td>Category Id</td>";

//Execute the Query Asynchronously
context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var itemInfo = '';
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        debugger;
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
            innerHtml += "<tr><td>" + currentListItem.get_item('Title') + "</td><tr>";
        }
        table.html(innerHtml);
    }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, fail)
    );

function fail() {
    debugger;
    alert(arguments[1].get_message());
}
```

Also would like to know how can i get top rows. My camlQuery giving all records now.

Comment: Here's a [Stack question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42910/get-url-of-image-from-picture-library-using-caml) that answers the image link portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SP.ListItem.attachmentFiles property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246450.aspx) to get the collection of attachments that are associated with the list item.

In order to load list items with attachments it have to be requested explicitly, for example:

```
ctx.load(items,'Include(AttachmentFiles)');
```

**Example**

The following example shows how to load list items with attachments

```
function getListItems(listTitle)
{ 
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var list =  web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
   ctx.load(items,'Include(AttachmentFiles)'); 
   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        deferred.resolve(items);
   },
   function(sender,args){
        deferred.reject(sender, args);
   });
   return deferred.promise();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var listTitle = 'Tasks';
getListItems(listTitle).then(renderSlideshow,logError);

function logError(sender,args){
   console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
}

function renderSlideshow(items){
   items.get_data().forEach(function(item){
       var attachmentFiles = item.get_attachmentFiles().get_data();
       attachmentFiles.forEach(function(attachmentFile){
          var url = attachmentFile.get_serverRelativeUrl();
          var name = attachmentFile.get_fileName();
          //...
       });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the top rows, order by the column which is base to identify the top rows. Update the CAML query to order by.

Comment: Please tell me how